# How to determine positions to draw lines on a screen with AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-physics

I have a screen (480x800), M(mx, my) is a static point, and N(nx,ny) is a dynamic point on screen. Position of N(nx, ny) depends position of touch. I want to determine position of P(?,?) and Q(?,?) to draw *line 1* and *line 2*. *line 2* is reflective *line 1*.

[image]

This is my code:

```
    private Line l2;

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene,
            final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if (this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Get position
                p1x = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                p1y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
                return true;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Remove instance of the old line
                mScene.detachChild(l2);

                p3x = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                p3y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

                Rectangle testR = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2,
                        CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, 20, 20,
                        getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                l2 = new Line(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, p3x, p3y,
                        getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                l2.setColor(new Color(223f / 255f, 118f / 255f, 43f / 255f));
                l2.setLineWidth(5);
                mScene.attachChild(l2);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If you have other ways to resolve my issue. Please share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't program with AndEngine for a while, but this isn't about AndEngine so I can give you a psedu code to solve your problem.

1) Check that nx < mx

2) Calculate the slope of line 1 :
line1slope = (my-ny)/(mx-nx)

3) Find P coordinates using the equation : y-y1 = m(x-x1)

Where m = line1slope

y1 = my

x1 = mx

y = 480 (P's y coordinate) ( if line1slope > 0 then y = 0)

And then you can find your x ( which is P's x coordinate)

line2slope = -1 * line1slope because they are reflective

Now again you need to find Q (You know the X = 0 so you need to find only the Y coordinate)
using the equation : y-y1 = m(x-x1)

Where m = line2slope

y1 = py

x1 = px

x = 0

And then you can find your y coordinate(which is Q's y coordinate)

Hope it helps.